# Разработка на ActionScript

Tags: actionscript

Вдруг, тут кто-то разрабатывал что-нибудь на ActionScript. Вопрос, чтобы делать полноценные приложения на нём, возможно работать к примеру только со связкой ActionScript 3 + FlashBuilder?

Comment: Что значит "полноценные приложения" ? Драйвер или кризис написать на ас3 нереально. А вот ЭнгриБёрдс со свистом.

Comment: Смотря какой драйвер :) Вон у "Танки Онлайн", свой 3D движок на флэше и живут же. Нет, я говорю о более тривиальной разработке. А так как мнения расходятся, я не знаю с какой стороны подступить. ЧИтать Колина Мука одно, а вот на чем разрабатывать - другое.

Comment: Драйвер - в смысле System Hardware Driver.

ас3 сейчас позволяет писать под все актуальные платформы, более того вести один проект под все эти платформы, ас3 разработчик вообще не пропадет на рынке, куча вакансий, да и синтаксис у него очень похож на java и c# :)

Comment: люди пишут на ас3 не только в flashbuilder, еще есть flashdevelop, idea, flash pro

Comment: Я с AS 3 перешёл на Java в январе прошлого года, так сейчас ищу работу по серверным технологиям

Answer (score 1):

Я работал флэшером, так я юзал и adobe flash, а ещё apach denver.

Comment: Флэшером в написание приложение или ближе к рисованию баннеров?

Comment: Не попал)) Написанием многопользовательских игр.